# How do I extend the Error class?

Tags: node.js, interface, typescript, joi

This is my code:

```
  let errorBadRequest = new Error("Bad request");

  res.statusCode = 400;
  errorBadRequest.errors = err.details.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    prev[current.path] = current.message;
    return prev;
  }, {});
  throw errorBadRequest;
```

I wanted to extend `error` attribute in error instance, but tsc said `joi-utils.ts(21,23): error TS2339: Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'Error'.`

The structure of `errors` is `{fieldname: fieldmsg}`, it's according to my joi request schema to decide.

How do I solve the error from typescript compiler? I think I need to declare a interface and be designate the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'Error'.

Create a file called `error-extension.d.ts` and have the following:

```
interface Error {
    errors: Error;
}
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Answer (score 0):

I find when initialing the `Error` class, actually it hasn't `errors` in `Error` . It should make a interface and set `errors` to option.

This is my solution:

```
interface IJoiErrorException extends NodeJS.ErrnoException {
  errors?: Object;
}

const errorBadRequest: IJoiErrorException = new Error("Bad request");
```